# Combining Render Passes Differs from Render Result in Blender 3.0 Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes

I have appeared to run into an issue with Blender when combining render passes in the newly released 3.0 version (Windows). It seems that whenever trying to reconstruct the rendered image via render passes, the result is slightly different from the image that was rendered, i.e. darker, less noticeable reflections. This is a test scene I made in a few minutes that showcases this issue: [image: Gif showcasing differences between rendered image and combined render passes with volumetrics.]

Oddly, this only happens when volumetrics are present in the scene, as when the volumes are disabled, there is no difference between the rendered image and the combined passes: [image: Gif showcasing no differences between rendered image and combined render passes without volumetrics.]

It is important to note that this problem **only occurs in Blender 3.0**. in Blender 2.93.6 there is no difference between the rendered image and the render passes. All guides on combining render passes, including the one in the [Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/layers/passes.html?), suggest this is the correct way to perform this. I have tried changing every setting I can think of, combining the passes in every possible way, and still cannot find a solution.

Download the [test scene here.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16p3ni088sBXMjj1Zd-vVMo2LD3hrxhdH/view)

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks for reading.

**UPDATE 01**

I believe I have found the cause. It appears that with Cycles-X, the **glossy indirect** pass does not reflect volumes or world lighting when volumetrics are present and cover a significant portion of the scene (such as world volumes). [image: Image showcasing glossy indirect pass with volumes.]
As visible, the glossy indirect pass in Blender 2.93.7 reflects world lighting and the volumetric object, whilst they are absent in Blender 3.0. I am beginning to think this is a problem the developers aren't aware of.

Again, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can report that as a Bug inside Blender go to Help > Report Bug

Comment: Thanks, reporting bug now.